# Run JMeter tests with Taurus sequentially

Tags: testing, jmeter, taurus

I would like to run a few JMeter scripts sequentially , one after the other, in Taurus.
I know that, as described [here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) , it is possible to run multiple JMeter tests in parallel using Taurus but I would need to have a setup script finish before any other future scripts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ExecutionSettings/#Startup-Schedule):

> By default, Taurus runs items under execution in parallel. To switch it into sequential mode, run it with `-sequential` command-line option.

If you want to make the change permanent - you can add the following block to [.bzt-rc configuration file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) (lives in your [HOME folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory)):

```
modules:
  local:
    sequential: true
```